# flutter: I want to display a Wrap that has a List of Text () including line breaks as a child, left-justified

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement a message that parses a URL from a string that contains the URL and displays that URL as a link.

```
test
https://google.com
test
```

I was able to parse the above string into the following array:

```
[test
, https://google.com,
test]
```

I implemented it as a child element of Wrap.

```
Wrap(
    children: [
        for (String str in strList)
            if (str.startsWith("http"))
                InkWell(
                    Text(str),
                    onTap: () {
                        launch(str);
                    }
                )
            else
                Text(str)
    ]
)
```

However, it will be displayed like the attached image.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QCrN.jpg)

What I expect is that the line breaks are displayed normally and are left justified.
Please give me advice.

(The above is just an example, and some do not include line breaks. Like this: `testhttps://google.com test`

If it does not include line breaks, it will be as follows.

```
[test, https://google.com, test]
```

If the character string does not include line breaks, there is no problem and only the URL in the character string will be a link.
)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want your address on line number one your date on line no 2 and your test is line number 1 on right side or left side ?

Answer (score 0):

How about you this implementation?

- loop strList
- If there is line breaks and rowChildren variable is not empty, add a rowChildren to rowChildrens list variable and reset rowChildren variable.
- If there is no line breaks, add a Widget to rowChildren variable.
- At last, add rowChildren variable to rowChildrens list variable.
- With list of rowChildrens, made a column's children

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    List strList = ['test', '\nhttps://google.com', '\ntest'];

    List<List<Widget>> rowsChildrens = [];
    List<Widget> rowChildren = [];
    for (var index = 0; index < strList.length; index++) {
      if (strList[index].startsWith('\n') && rowChildren.isNotEmpty) {
        rowsChildrens.add(rowChildren);
        rowChildren = [];
      }

      final String trimedStr = strList[index].trim();
      if (trimedStr.startsWith('http')) {
        rowChildren.add(
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print(trimedStr);
            },
            child: Text(trimedStr),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        rowChildren.add(
          Text(trimedStr),
        );
      }
    }
    rowsChildrens.add(rowChildren);

    return Column(
      children: rowsChildrens
          .map<Widget>((rowChildren) => Row(children: rowChildren))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The behavior is similar to what I expected in the first question, but the line breaks even if the string doesn't contain any line breaks.

Comment: If that, how about you use just one Text widget and joining string array and erase not needed space.(I changed code)

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it badly, but the reason why I set the string to List is to detect the URL and link only that string.
So I can't implement the original purpose when joining.

Comment: Let me know your string array value included line break.

Comment: Is that reason? I'm trying to make a messenger app. The sent message contains line breaks, URLs, etc. I want to make a URL a link.

Comment: With your code I can not reproduce like attached screenshot although I added a line break '\n' to string.

Comment: I changed again. I think it is what you want.